# How to add new row below previous one in tableview

Tags: android

I want to add a new row below previous ones. I mean I have a UI containing 2 text boxes and 1 submit button. When I fill the text box and press submit, the content of text box is added below the previous one. Is this done with listview or tableview?

Please give suggestions to me and how to implement that technique. And after item is added in listview and when I click on any of list position, it performs different-2 activity. And I am new in Android.

```
TextView exampleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.field1);
exampleTextView.setText("wedwqe");
TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
TableRow tr = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.row);
tr.addView(exampleTextView);
//  table.removeView(tr);
table.addView(tr);
```

And the XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#DDDDDD"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/row">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/field1"
        android:text=" "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18dip"
    />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/field2"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text=" "
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:gravity="right"
    />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addView(View child, int index)` that you can find in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29)

I hope this helps

Comment: TextView exampleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.field1);
         exampleTextView.setText("wedwqe");
         TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
         TableRow tr = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.row);
         tr.addView(exampleTextView);
       //  table.removeView(tr);
         table.addView(tr);

Comment: it gives error and force close ......The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you want to do, but `examokeTextView` already belongs to a parent, so you can get its parent with `parent=getParent()` then remove the view with `parent.removeView(exampleTextView)` and then add it to `tr`.